# Why do some functional languages not use parenthesis for function arguments?

Tags: functional-programming

I've been trying to a adopt a functional language into my programing. I use C# and rely heavily on LINQ and other functional constructs. Currently I'm focusing on Elm.

One thing that continues to bother me is the lack of parenthesis in functions. Math expressions use them:

```
f(z) = ln(z) + 1
```

Yet in many functional languages this is written as:

```
f z = ln z + 1
```

It this just a style thing or is there something deeper going here?

Comment: While interesting and there are definitely some cases for not having parenthesis in a curried language like Haskell I really want to say it's largely "opinion based" of the language syntax designers. Arguments otherwise should illustrate how lack of parenthesis is (or can be) *beneficial* to certain functional-programming concepts. LISP dialects (with various degrees of 'functional-programming') on the other hand can't live without parenthesis..

Comment: I'm not sure how come you say "some".. You have Fortran  an it's dialects (Algol, Basic, C, pyhon, perl, java, C#, pascal to name a few)  that uses `f(arg ...)`, then you have lisp dialects (Scheme, Common Lisp, Arc) with `(f arg ...)`, We have SASL dialects (Haskell) which uses `f arg : args =`.  Am I mising something. Where are all the **different** languages which uses `f(arg)` or are we only talking about [Fortran dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#Fortran_based)?

Comment: @Sylwester Contrast "some" (any number of) with "all" or "many" or "most". Feel free to edit the title to improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functional languages take root in [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), which do not use parentheses for functional application.

It is a syntactical thing sure, but the way that functions are applied it makes sense to leave parentheses out since a function with two arguments first applies the left most argument to the function and output a function that is used by the second argument. For example the function you are used to:

```
add(x,y) { return x + y }
```

in functional terms is

```
add x y
add :: Int->Int->Int
```

where the intermediate step after applying x returns another function

```
add 4  -- returns a function that will return 4 + y, when y is applied
add 4 :: Int->Int
```

To a certain degree this helps avoid confusion with the programming languages you are used to where add(4) would throw an error. It reads more like math with associativity, `((add x) y)`.

Comment: That makes sense. Wondering how I missed that concept of function application. Obviously, I was thinking of function taking parameters instead of function applying parameters.

Answer (score 4):

One of the reasons to avoid parenthesis in function application is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

If you code `f x y`  (like you should in Ocaml) then `f x`  is simply a curryfication. If you don't have such a notation, you need an explicit lambda (or some [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) notation), like in Scheme `(lambda (y) (f x y))`

On the other hand, languages with currying often implicitly interpret `f x y`  as `(f x) y` and then their implementation need to optimize that to avoid creating useless temporary [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

<sup>I have mixed feelings w.r.t. currying. It is perhaps not often useful (but you'll need it sometimes), and a *short* anonymous function notation is perhaps enough</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Alot of the notation we see is influenced my mathematics, and I've seen atleast two types of function notation within maths to show domain to codomain mapping.

f(x) = x + 1 and x -> x + 1

So I guess maybe the languages without parenthesis derive from the later maybe